# "$(...).find(...)" in onclick-eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for the click handling on a button inside my page:

```
$(document).on("click", $('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection"), function (e) {
        addItemToDocumentGrid();
        $('#removeDocumentFromSection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
        $('#removeSelection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
});
```

But the event fires as soon as I click anywhere in the page. Even if it is not the supposed button which I want to select with `$('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection")`.

`$('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection")` returns one element which is actually the button which I want to be selected.

Why does it behave like that?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use event delegation, the second argument should be a *selector*, not a jQuery object.

```
$(document).on("click", '#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType + " .addDocumentToSection", function (e) {
// ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        addItemToDocumentGrid();
        $('#removeDocumentFromSection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
        $('#removeSelection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
});
```

If you don't want to use event delegation, you need to call `on` on the element you want to hook the event on:

```
$('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection").on("click", function (e) {
        addItemToDocumentGrid();
        $('#removeDocumentFromSection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
        $('#removeSelection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
});
```

This is all covered in [the `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: @TânNguyễn: Or people read fast. Doesn't take more than 10-15 seconds, if that, to read the above if you're familiar with the concepts.

Comment: @TânNguyễn also as likely : people reading the question, see the obvious answer, go to add answer, get notification that an answer has been added, see that it's exactly what they would put, upvote rather than add a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching onClick event to a `document` element. Try:

```
var button = $('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection");
button.on("click", function() {
    addItemToDocumentGrid();
    $('#removeDocumentFromSection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
    $('#removeSelection').disable(true).addClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: The downvotes on this seem harsh. We don't know the OP wants to use event delegation, and the OP says the selector does find the relevant element; given that, this says both what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Upvoted to balance: given that the `$().find()` is working, it seems reasonable that there's no need for event delegation, giving this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#' + GlobalVariables.currentUserType).find(".addDocumentToSection").on("click", function(e){

});
```

jQuery can use selectors before the `.on("click"`, this should work for you.